# Speeding up VBA Code that Sets Pivot Table Filters

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've written out some VBA code that sets various filters onto pivottables. The problem I am experiencing is that it is extremely slow and bogs down my system heavily.

I've tried implementing various things to speed up the code, but nothing really has that much of an effect.

The reason I am doing it this way is the filters need to be dynamic and I am using multiple data sources, so just using a single slicer doesn't work in my case.

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Dim DivRef, RegRef, DistRef, ZoneRef As String
    DivRef = Sheet5.Range("AH6").Value
    RegRef = Sheet5.Range("AH7").Value
    DistRef = Sheet5.Range("AH8").Value
    ZoneRef = Sheet5.Range("AN4").Value

With Sheet5.PivotTables("PivotTable21")
    .ManualUpdate = True
    .PivotFields("Division2").CurrentPage = DivRef
    .PivotFields("Region2").CurrentPage = RegRef
    .PivotFields("District2").CurrentPage = DistRef
    .ManualUpdate = False
End With


With Sheet5.PivotTables("PivotTable9")
    .ManualUpdate = True
    .PivotFields("Division2").CurrentPage = DivRef
    .PivotFields("Region2").CurrentPage = RegRef
    .PivotFields("District2").CurrentPage = DistRef
    .ManualUpdate = False
  End With

     Application.EnableEvents = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End Sub
```

In reality, there are a number of pivottables that are being filtered, but for the sake of this post, I am only posting PivotTable21 and PivotTable9's filters, though it is all more or less the same code.

I've been told that part of the problem might be that I am using calculated fields in my pivottables, and that may bog down some of the code as well.

Does anyone have any tips for speeding this code up?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BruceWayne It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela - So I can recommend they post there, and if OP does, then wouldn't that be duplicating posts on SE?  Is that okay, having same exact question on two SE networks?  But thanks for the link to the guide, I'll read through it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code...you're doing everything right, and this will be as fast as it gets. Can you tell us more about the calculated fields you're using? Are they written using DAX? (I.e. is this a PowerPivot PivotTable) Or are these the old-school Calculated Fields available under traditional PivotTables? Maybe you could add a screenshot of the calculated fields to your question.

Comment: This is the old school calculated field used in pivottables. Unfortunately I'm not able to use PowerPivot for this report. The calculated field is fairly straight forward. In the source data, there is 1 field for Employee Hours and 1 field for Employee Injuries. The calculated field is: =(sum(Employee Injuries)*200000)/sum(Hours)

Comment: @BruceWayne Presuming there are no answers, the OP can remove the post on one site and post it on another site (albeit after a grace period for new users). If there are answers on the original post, then hopefully closing the question would suffice...